# Node.JS fetch posting to a webpage doesn't seems to work

Tags: web-scraping, fetch-api

I'm attempting to scrape data from a webform problem is that when I try to simulate behavious of a browser in Node.JS using fetch the web page returns a page with no changes (meaning even if a success or an error is expected it would return the initial page that would been seen if no information is entered).

I'm guessing I have something wrong with the body portion of the fetch but I'm unsure, Here is a minimally reproducible example demonstrating the issue:

```js
    import gm from 'gm'
    import { recognize } from "node-tesseract-ocr";
    function getCaptcha(html) {
    return html.split('<img id="imgKontrol" src="')[1].split('"')[0]
}
function getValueById(html, id) {
    return html.split(`id="${id}"`)[1].split('value="')[1].split('"')[0]
}
    const diplomaPage = await fetch('https://eokulyd.meb.gov.tr/IlkOgretim/MEM/IOM00010.aspx')
    
    const diplomaPage2 = await fetch('https://eokulyd.meb.gov.tr/IlkOgretim/MEM/IOM00010.aspx', {
        headers: {
            'cookie': diplomaPage.headers.get('set-cookie').split(';')[0]
        }
    })

    const diplomaPage2HTML = await diplomaPage2.text()

    const viewState          = getValueById(diplomaPage2HTML, "__VIEWSTATE")
    const viewStateGenerator = getValueById(diplomaPage2HTML, "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")
    const eventValidation    = getValueById(diplomaPage2HTML, "__EVENTVALIDATION")
    const captchaImageBase64 = getCaptcha(diplomaPage2HTML).replace('data:image/png;base64,', '')
    
  
    const captcha_image = gm(Buffer.from(captchaImageBase64, 'base64'))
    captcha_image.whiteThreshold('72%').blackThreshold('80%').blur(2, 3).whiteThreshold('75%').motionBlur(2).blackThreshold('90%').blur(2, 3)
    .toBuffer('png', async (err, buffer) => {
        const ocr = await recognize(Buffer.from(buffer, 'base64'), { lang: 'eng', psm: 4, presets: ['digits'], tessedit_char_whitelist: "0123456789" })
        const diplomaSorgu = await fetch('https://eokulyd.meb.gov.tr/IlkOgretim/MEM/IOM00010.aspx', {
            body: new URLSearchParams({viewState, viewStateGenerator, eventValidation, txtFormKontrol: ocr, btnGiris: 'Sorgula', hdnKontrol: 'evet'}),
            headers: {
                "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
                "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                "cache-control": "max-age=0",
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
                "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
                "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
                "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
                "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",                
                'cookie': diplomaPage.headers.get('set-cookie').split(';')[0],
                "Referer": "https://eokulyd.meb.gov.tr/IlkOgretim/MEM/IOM00010.aspx",
                "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            },
            method: 'POST'
        })          
        
        console.log(await diplomaSorgu.text())
    })
```

(don't mind the styling or missing images, those are not important and images are for reference only to show what I want)
**Examples:**
Expected (Wrong Captcha Error):

[image: Wrong Captcha]

**Got:**

[image: Wrong Captcha but it does not show up]

I would expect to see Wrong Captcha warning here but I did not.

There are no indications of error or success when I do request through my code I just get the Initial web form , I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).